# How to design a worm-gear in FreeCAD?

Tags: 3d-models, cad, freecad

I want to print worm gears for my robot arm. I would like to design it in FreeCAD. Normally, I would use *involute gear* for regular gears. However, this tool cannot be used for worm gears. I can't find any add-ons for this.

Is it possible to produce a worm gear automatically? If not, how can I make it manually?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as I know there is not a workbench capable of producing the design you want with a single click "new worm gear".  But it is a rather simple affair to create the part you want from scratch.

What you want to do is to sweep a *sketch* along a *helix*.  It is a very similar process to the one you would follow to create a thread documented in the [official tutorial](https://www.freecadweb.org/wiki/Thread_for_Screw_Tutorial) (it's the "method #3" on that page).  This is how it should look like:

[image]

Since helices are subject to a few limitation in FreeCAD, I recommend to read the section called "tricks to success" and the following tips, as it is *very likely* you will incur in problems otherwise.